# Can my ISP get my laptop Device ID and Product ID?

Tags: mac, internet, ip, privacy, isp

Can the ISP get my laptop Device ID and Product ID shown on the settings of my device?

I know ISP can get MAC address and IP address, can they get more than that?

Answer (score 1):

ISP assigns you your router's IP address. So if you router does NATTing, it will not get yur PC's MAC address.

Whatever is transmitted on wire in HTTP can be intercepted by your ISP and can be read. By default, your PC Device ID and Product ID is not sent on wire. But if it is, then ISP will come to know.

Browsers send a user agent string that contains the browser, OS info etc and the websites can find out the OS language, languages installed etc from the browser. You can check what is sent out using tools like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Not sure what prompted you to ask this question. Details on that will help us give you a more precise answer.

Comment: Even if an IP router doesn’t use NAT, Layer 2 addresses won’t leave the network.

Comment: @DanielB Not if the PC is directly connected with say a wifi dongle that directly assigns a public address to the PC or the dongle belongs to the ISP. Hence the comment

Comment: Even then, the MAC address will be visible to the router only. Of course, the router may share that knowledge. And then, constructing arbitrary scenarios where the ISP learns the MAC address is always possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless your device is comprimised or you otherwise provide access.

The MAC address does give a hint to the manufacturer, and could potentially be used to guess at the device. The following page can tell you the manufacturer (or assigned owner) of a range of MAC addresses: https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html

It's also important to note that your ISP will not be able to determine your PC's MAC address if it's behind a router - they will only be able to see the router's WAN-side MAC address, if one is used for your connection type.

MAC addresses are used at Layer 1 and 2, meaning that once IP routing comes into play, the MAC address is not consistent throught the connection's full path.

Comment: Except most computers are behind some kind of router, so no MAC is sent to the ISP.

Comment: I think by "_no MAC_" you mean "_just the router's MAC_"? I agree that the PC's MAC will not be available to the ISP when it's behind a router .

Comment: Correct - assuming the connection method to the ISP us Ethernet like (I don't think any MAC is passed on a PPPoA connection for example)

Answer (score 0):

MAC addresses are only sent on the same subnet, do if you have any kind of router, the ISP will not be able to get your MAC. If an ISP can somehow get your MAC address, and you have not changed it, they can get the make of your device, and a unique identifiers. Of-course, it's generally not that hard to change the MAC address used (can be done in software and often firmware as well)

Unless the ISP can trick/coerce you into running software to gather and send back this information , or it can somehow intercept and decrypt (or obtain in clear text) when another program is transmitting this information (eg license key validation) they can't get any product IDs.

In rare cases (depending on how you connect) it may be possible to fingerprint the IP stack to make an informed guess about the OS - similarly if you can be persuaded to visit certain ISP controlled pages they can gather information about your system - but not typically a unique product code.